# extract features from parts of one image

Tags: keras, image-classification, pytorch, feature-extraction

I have several parts of one image that have one caption... I need to do image captioning by evaluating every part of the image to which the caption will belong so do I need to extract the features from parts of the image and pass it to the model with its caption ? or how can I do it please?

for example; the dataset I have are the parts of the image which are divided into three parts “beach, sea, dog”, and the caption I have for the three parts is one caption which is "a dog at the beach" . is there any way to extract features for those parts as one image? does concatenate features will be the same feature as the original image

I need to evaluate every part of the image to which the caption will belong

Comment: too broad question

Comment: I think the question is for a specific task or what is wrong with the question, please?

Comment: asking people to tell you how to do a certain task like that from scratch, is broad, what would invite answers is for example to have something already working and asking for help for some specific part

Comment: no, i have an idea but I think it is false, i edit the post with the example

Comment: See : https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-caption-photos-with-deep-learning/